# Maximum principle and Lipschitz continuous

Tags: partial-differential-equations, ricci-flow

Let $(M,g(t))$ is a Ricci flow. And
$$
\Box = \partial_t -\Delta_{g(t)}
$$
is heat operator, which coupled to Ricci flow. If
$$
\Box u =0  
~~~~~~\text{and }~~~~~~
\Box |\nabla u|\le 0
$$
Then how to show

> If  $u(\cdot, t_1)$ is L-Lipschitz, then so is $u(\cdot, t)$ for all $t\ge t_1$.

This problem is from the  7th page of [Entropy and heat kernel bounds on a Ricci flow background](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.07093.pdf). Namely the picture below.

> > [image]

Comment: Isn't $L$ more or less the sup norm of $|\nabla u|$?

Comment: @ArcticChar   Thanks your hint. I have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Arctic Char's hint, I have an answer.  I use the follow maximum principle,which is from Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow.

> [image]

Besides, $u$ is smooth (I forgot it earlier). Since  $|\nabla u(\cdot, t_1)|\le L$, in the theorem 3.1.1, letting  $ X(t)=0, F(u,t)=0, \alpha=L$, then $\phi(t)=L$. Therefore, I have
$$
|\nabla u(\cdot,t)|\le L   ~~~\forall t\ge t_1
$$
namely, $u(\cdot,t)$ is L-Lipschitz.